# javac arregloClass.java > arregloClass.java:6: error: cannot find symbol > dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tengo un error, en un arreglo que estoy haciendo con menú, pero este, este tiene que ser inicializado en la clase principal, pero ser jalado en la clase secundaria la cual tiene los métodos de inserción del tamaño, inserción de datos e impresión, el error es que no recibe datos la variable `array[i]`, código:

Clase principal:

```
import java.io.*;
public class arregloM{
public static void main(String args [])throws IOException{
    BufferedReader al = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int [] array = null;
    int op=0;
    arregloClass class = new arregloClass();
    boolean reto = true;
    while(reto){
        System.out.printl("\n Bienvendio :D");
        System.out.printl("1.- Ingresar Tamano");
        System.out.printl("2.- Ingresar datos");
        System.out.printl("3.- Mostrar datos");
        System.out.printl("4.- Salir");
        op = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
if(op == 1){       
            class.tamano();
        }
        else if(op == 2){
            class.datos();
        }
        else if(op == 3){
            class.mostrar();
        }
        else if(op==4){
            reto = false;
        }
    } } }
```

Clase secundaria:

```
class arregloClass{

    public static void tamano(int array[]){
        int dato=0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamano del arreglo");
        dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
        array = new int[dato];
    }
    public static void datos(int array[], int dato){
        for(int i=0; i<dato; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus datos");
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());       
       } 
    }
    public static void mostrar(int array[], int dato){
        System.out.println("\n Sus datos son");
        for(int i=0; i<dato;i++){
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

El error:

> ```
> PS C:\j> javac arregloClass.java
>    arregloClass.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>    dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
>                                ^
>
>  symbol:   variable al
>   location: class arregloClass
>
>    arregloClass.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
>            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());       
>                                        ^
>            symbol:   variable al
>            location: class arregloClass
>              2 errors
> ```

Comment: Entre otras cosas, la variable que utilizas "al" no está declarada

Comment: Tienes muchos errores de compilación a parte del error que muestras, por ejemplo, te falta añadir la 'n' en el system.out. Además, con esto 'dato = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());' No estás pidiendo datos al usuario...